using prefers-color-scheme in the server side rendering
I have a website with dark and light themes (styles, logos, fav icon) and it's with server side rendering
this is a mock of the code I run on the runtime
const darkTheme = media.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
changeFavicon(darkTheme.matches);
(
  darkTheme.addEventListener as MediaQueryList['addEventListener'] | undefined
)?.('change', ($event) => {
  changeFavicon($event.matches);
});

function changeFavicon(isDark: boolean): void {
  const favicon = document.getElementById('favicon') as HTMLLinkElement;

  if (isDark) {
    favicon.href = 'favicon.ico';
  } else {
    favicon.href = 'light-favicon.ico';
  }
}

is there anyway to make this to work in the SSR (I'm using Angular, but this applies to any website), so that the user don't start with the default theme then switch to another?

Vue.js has a function called beforeMount() that will perform an action before rendering the page. If Angular has something like that, you can read the preference first, then use that theme to render the page without a flash between the default and the preference.
Whats the angular equivalent to Vue's beforeMount?
